# Is my third party service instance which is wrapped inside another service being disposed in case of a transient lifetime registration in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, object-lifetime

I have created a AwsS3Service which is used to upload files to AWS S3, and I am creating an AmazonS3Client from 'AWSSDK.S3' nuget package inside the constructor. I am also implementing  the IDisposable interface for my custom service, and disposing the AmazonS3Client client inside of it.

My question is, if I register AwsS3Service as a transient service, does AmazonS3Client gets disposed after each time I request my service? If not, could you please suggest a better way to implement this. I don't want the AmazonS3Client to be hanging around in the memory.

*IAwsS3Service interface*

```
public interface IAwsS3Service : IDisposable
{
    public Task<bool> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file, string fileName, string path);
}
```

*AwsS3Service*

```
public class AwsS3Service : IAwsS3Service
{
    private readonly IAmazonS3 _client;
        
    public AwsS3Service()
    {
        _client = new AmazonS3Client(/* secret and access keys are read from appsettings and passed */);
    }

    public async Task<bool> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file, string fileName, string awsPath)
    {
       // uploading logic..
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IAwsS3Service, AwsS3Service>();
}
```

Comment: Would suggest create a AWSClientService and use DI to inject it into this service.  I would say mainly keep these services as scoped unless you have specific reason for transient.

Comment: @AliK If I change it to scoped let's say, is AmazonS3Client still going to be disposed?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about here?  The client will be disposed once its no longer used GC will dispose of it either way.

Comment: @AliK I just wanna understand, will AmazonS3Client instances be disposed when AwsS3Service  is disposed or I will have a pile of them hanging in the memory